# Clientside socket.io get SessionID

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I want to get current ClientSessionID from a user's browser window with javascript

Basically something like this:

```
var io = io (  );
io.emit ( 'Command', {id: /* Client ID HERE */ }, parameters: [ 'hello', 'world' ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to pass your stuff in one json by parameters like this:

```
var myJson={
id:1,
parameters:["hello", "word"]
}

io.emit ("command", myJson);
```

Comment: in fact, you never showed how to make this into a json string, please atleast edit your answer so it matches with your "explination" xD

Comment: I´m showing it... I defined the json and then I put it into the message... What you need to do here is to unwrap the json in the socket that receives the parameter...

Comment: Also, please have a look at http://socket.io/ and you'll understand that it is not because of the object, what I want is to get an send the Socket Client ID to the server...